# All instances in one Nest.js microservice are subscribing the same message at the same time when using Redis transport

Tags: redis, microservices, nest

I've created a new project with nest.js & microservices and choose the transport option as Redis. It's working fine when I use only one instance per microservice, but when I create multiple instances for one microservice, all instances are subscribing messages at the same time.
For instance, let's say there are 1 api gateway (publisher) and 3 instances for product management microservices. When the api gateway is publishing a message to create a product, then 3 instances are subscribing the same message and create 3 same products.

I think there should be some kind of load balancing of subscribing messages or other option.

Is there any one to know what is the best trasport option for this purpose and how to build multiple instances per microservices.

Comment: Have you found any solutions to this?

Answer (score 0):

Redis PUB/SUB by default publishes all messages to all clients. You are unfortunately limited to one instance per message listened. Alternatives are to implement a custom transport using Redis Streams or a combination of PUB/SUB and streams if you still want to use Redis as the solution.

There aren't any open source packages that are currently supporting Streams. Here is the comment from Kamil relating to this https://github.com/nestjs/nest/issues/3960#issuecomment-771647374